# vim -- how to do multiple search-and-replace operations on a visual block?

Tags: vim, replace

Suppose I have some code,

```
struct NodeVector {
    vector<bool_node*> *vec;
};
```

I want to replace two things, like this,

```
:'<,'>s/NodeVector/MyClass/g | s/bool_node/MyEltClass/g
```

but, it only runs the first search, and then says "pattern not found: `bool_node`". How can I achieve this result? (plugin answers are okay).

```
struct MyClass {
    vector<MyEltClass*> *vec;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that both of the search & replace commands need a range. For example, these should work fine:

```
:'<,'>s/NodeVector/MyClass/g | '<,'>s/bool_node/MyEltClass/g
```

or

```
:%s/NodeVector/MyClass/g | %s/bool_node/MyEltClass/g
```

Answer (score 1):

`vim` treats `|`(bar) differently after `:global` command, so you can do this:

```
:'<,'>g/^/s/NodeVector/MyClass/g | s/bool_node/MyEltClass/g
```

Comment: not differently. But the order in which the parsing is done causes the `|` to be part of the command argument for `g`

Answer (score 1):

In default setups you can shorten it:

```
:*s/NodeVector/MyClass/g | *s/bool_node/MyEltClass/g
```

This is because, normally <sup>1</sup>, `:*` is a synonym for `:'<,'>`

---

<sup>1</sup> unless `*` is in `cpoptions` (*vi compatibility options*), which it isn't by default